# box-shadow накладывается на родителя

Tags: html, css

Код:

```js
  $('.window').draggable({
   handle: ".window-handle"
  });
```

```css
.window {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #eee;
 position: absolute;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        top:30px;
 }
.window-handle {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 position: absolute;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 top: -20px;
}
.exit {
 float: right;
 color:white;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <div class="window hello">
  <div class="window-handle">
  title
   <span class="exit">&times;</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Видно что `box-shadow:;` блока с текстом title накладывается на родителя а мне нужно чтобы не блок родителя не накладывался и не дочерний блок т.е. так

[image: title]

Comment: Я как то не понял кто на кого накладывается? как я вижу нормально все.

Comment: А вы запускали код?

Comment: да конечно, вы объяснять подробно на каких блоках должно быть `shadow`? и в каких сторонах

Comment: На картинке показано как ожидается

Comment: что то путаете вы или не правильно объясняете.

Comment: На двух блоках. Но чтобы на стыке не было box shadow http://imgur.com/E2Ywdrb.

Comment: ну вот так бы сказали сразу в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит использовать тень только на `.window, и сделать нужный паддинг внутри него.

```js
$('.window').draggable({
  handle: ".window-handle"
});
```

```css
.window {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.window-handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.exit {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="window hello">
  <div class="window-handle">
    title
    <span class="exit">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас все правильно работает, просто неправильно определили `box-shadow`. Попробуйте это:

```js
$('.window').draggable({
    handle: ".window-handle"
});
```

```css
.window {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #eee;
   position: absolute;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   top:30px; 
}

.window-handle {
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   box-shadow: 0px -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
}

.exit {
   float: right;
   color:white;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="window hello">
   <div class="window-handle">
       title
       <span class="exit">&times;</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо но ответ выше лучше в плане отображения